# Get CollectionView cells that are invisible

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

### Intro

> I know that this topic has been discussed a lot on StackOverflow and
>   am aware that a **Collection View recycles its cells**.
>
> However, I have not found a suitable explanation for the problem I
>   describe below.

### Problem

In my app, I have a collection view that has **multiple cell types** in it - each cell **only exists once** in the collection view.

The collection view **acts like a form** in which the user can enter different things - split up on a few cells.

If I now scroll down, the first cell is **not visible** anymore. However, it is also **not removed** from the collection view as the entered data is still correctly displayed if I scroll back to the top.

> If a user clicks a button, I am fetching every collection view cell
>   from the collection view and run a validation method on it.

**Just like the following:**

```
let firstCell = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as! DefaultElementCell // get the cell

firstCell.validateEntries() // validates entries and highlights incorrect fields
```

If I now **scroll to the bottom** of the collection view (the last cell), I get an ***error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"***. The optional value in this case is the Cell that should be returned by *cellForItemAt()*.

> So, I think that the cell has already been removed but on the other
>   hand the text entered into the fields and everything are still there
>   if I scroll back to the first cell.

### What I tried:

```
if let firstCell = myCollectionView.dataSource?.collectionView(self.myCollectionView, cellForItemAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) {
            print((firstCell as! DefaultElementCell).validateEntries()) // does nothing
}
```

**Now, I don't get the error "unexpectedly found nil" anymore but *validateEntries() also does nothing* anymore.**

Is there any way I can correctly get the invisible collection view cells or prevent the collection view from re-using cells? As already mentioned, every cell type only exists once in the collection view.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: It seems that you are (mis)using the cells as data source.

Comment: what kind of ui elemnts you use all textfields ??

Comment: All text fields @Sh_Khan

Comment: @MartinR would you mind explaining what I am misunderstanding? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The cells are only for displaying data. The actual data should always be in your model object.

Comment: The cells only display the model data that you assign them in the `cellForItemAt indexPath` method. Your cell data should be in the `dataSource` (e.x. an array of objects) that you use to populate the collection view cells. So, if you need to access the data at any moment, you would use your `dataSource`, not the collection view itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of same size as you number of cells then

```
var arr = [String]() 

 // inside cellForRowAt 
cell.textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged
cell.textfield.tag = indexPath.item
```

and

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
   arr[textfiled.tag] = textfield.text!
}
```

then validate you entry from `arr` values